# Does IPv6 link local address as default gateway break forwarding?

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, dsl, pppoe

I have a Linux machine with two Ethernet interfaces and one is connected to VDSL over converter. The PPPoE connection works fine, but routing doesn't work. I've set the proper kernel config parameters:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ppp0.accept_ra = 2
```

I can ping to any host in Internet from router over IPv4 and even IPv6. However, ping from other hosts works over IPv4 only. Then I've found something, that might matter, I think:

```
root@router$ ip -6 route show
...
default via fe80::427c:7dff:fee6:7f03 dev ppp0 metric 1024 pref medium
```

PPPoE connection configures default route using link local address. Can that disturb the routing, please? Is to replace the link local address with a full IPv6 address of the *next-hop*  (the closest provider's) router?

Or do I need explicitly to forward some advertisements or solicitations, that IPv6 needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending packets to the default gateway on your network funnily enough doesn't use the IP address of the gateway. The source address will be that of your machine and the destination address is that of the final destination. Sending the packet through the default gateway happens on layer-2: the MAC address on an ethernet network, or just to the other end of a connection when sending it through a point-to-point link like PPP.

So as long as your next hop resolves to the right MAC address or point-to-point interface everything will be fine. In the packet the IPv4/IPv6 address of the gateway is never used.

Comment: I found the cause finally. I used fixed addresses and my provider had changed  the prefix meanwhile. The cause was - we can call it - IPv6 prefix mismatch. To fix the prefix almost solved the problem. However then I experienced some disruptions when HTTPS on client used. My provider limits MTU from default 1500 bytes to 1492. The RADVD daemon has to provide MTU to clients in that case. Now it all works perfect.